# Mapping between a port and a process id

Tags: sockets, network-programming, operating-system

When a packet is routed to the destination, it uses a port number to map it to and appropriate process at the server. However, I do not find any documentation on how the mapping of (port- process) is done. Please let me know with some interesting links/references. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The operating knows which process has which ports open, that's about it in general terms. A specific answer would require specifying a specific operating system, but you can guess that there is something like a port control block for each port and that it probably contains the PID of the process that owns it, or a pointer to its process control block, etc.